# Cannot bind to JPlayer event on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, audio, jplayer

I'm using jplayer for playing audio on a webpage, and when the page loads, the inspector and the player get loaded fine, but the bind function does not work. If I call it later from the console then it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
        { mp3: flatplaylist[0] },
        { supplied: "mp3", }
    );
    $("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
    //does not work from here, but will work if I put this in the console.
    $(myCirclePlayer.audio).bind('ended',function (){ playNextFile(); }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my final code, which works fine.

```
var PlayerID = "#jquery_jplayer_1";
$(window).ready(function(){
    myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer(PlayerID,{mp3: 'audio/'+mypl.playlist[0]},{supplied: "mp3",});
    $("#jplayer_inspector").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
    $(PlayerID).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function (){ playNextFile(); });
});
```